# How to install different subversions of Python

Tags: python, windows, installation

I need to:

1. Install Python 3.5.0 and Python 3.5.4.
2. Be able to be able to create a virtual-env for both sub-versions.
3. Have a solution that works with Windows.

---

1. I can't install Python 3.5.4 and then install Python 3.5.0:

   [image: A newer version of Python 3.5 is already installed.]
2. I can't use [`pyenv` as it doesn't support windows](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/62).
3. I can't use [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-python) as it doesn't allow you to pick 3.5.0.
4. I can't use [the embeddable zip file](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/) as it doesn't come with venv support.

---

How can I install both Python 3.5.0 and 3.5.4 on Windows?

Comment: have you tried pipenv?

Comment: @JoelBerkeley No, not come across it.

Comment: tbh i'm surprised I can't find a duplicate of this qu

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot about running 3.6 and 3.5, but couldn't find any for this.

Comment: The [nuget releases](https://www.nuget.org/packages/python) only go back to 3.5.2. They don't come with venv anyway (a recent issue addressed this, so new releases should get venv, but I don't think older releases will be rebuilt). Try [WinPython](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/files/WinPython_3.5).